# rownum is not returning anything even if without rownum a record is shown

Tags: sql, plsql, db2

I have a select statement in DB2 that returns a record when executed however if I add a restriction like `rownum >=1 and rownum <=2` no record is being returned.

Select statement:

When I try with:

```
SELECT person.ID, person.SEX, person.BYEAR, person.BMONTH,
        person.BDAY
        FROM MIGRATION.LEGALPERSON person
        JOIN MIGRATION.LEGALPARTNER part ON person.ID = part.ID 
        WHERE person.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
```

one record is returned.

And with the

```
SELECT person.ID, person.SEX, person.BYEAR, person.BMONTH,
            person.BDAY
            FROM MIGRATION.LEGALPERSON person
            JOIN MIGRATION.LEGALPARTNER part ON person.ID = part.ID 
            WHERE person.STATUS = 'ACTIVE' and person.ROWNUM >= 1 and person.ROWNUM <= 2
```

no record is returned.

What could be the root cause?

Comment: Can you add some data to your question?

Comment: add all the details where you getting failed

Answer (score 1):

You can't use rownum that way (see documentation, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm):

> Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer are always false

If you want to do something like that, consider using `row_number` analytic function, e.g.

```
with temp as
  (select some_column,
          row_number() over (order by date_value) rn
   from your_table
  )
select *
from temp
where rn between 4 and 13
```

---

As of `ROWNUM` itself:

```
with temp as
  (select some_column,
          rownum rn
   from your_table
   order by date_value
  )
select *
from temp
where rn between 4 and 13
```

Comment: I think your assumprion is not correct for db2 databases. I have tested the select statement with between and I not getting any record returned :-(

Comment: Ah, DB2 ... it was the plsql tag that lead me to this question. However, if analytic functions work the same way in Oracle and DB2 (they should, I presume); then it *should* work. Anyway, I've edited my message by adding the ROWNUM example. See whether it helps.